# Resource linking failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-components-android

I am working with Android Studio, and I am trying to use google material library

I am getting the following error (**Android resource linking failed**):

> ERROR:AAPT: C:\Users\ANDRES\Desktop\cursillo_android\TipTime2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

Mi grade files are:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tiptime2"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'


}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I would like to share a picture of the error with you:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When your targetSdk is below 31 then the support library associated
with material resources will be in conflict with your build configuration.

During the build, gradle will use a task to check all support .aar libraries
metadata, where build target compatibility is set; in the case of
com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05' the target compatibility
is set above 30 (may be 31, or even higher);
Remedy is this:
So go to an earlier material support library from
here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
to use an earlier support version of the material support class;

Comment: This should be the right answer ! Works for me !

Answer (score 0):

Try removing  'implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0-alpha01' in gradle(Module), works fine.